# ¿Se puede usar un plugin de cordova o npm con ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic, npm, cordova

Quería saber si es posible instalar un plugin disponible para iOS o Android en Ionic 3 y usarlo.

He llegado a instalarlo, pero a la hora de usarlo no se como hacerlo ya que no es nativo, es simplemente un plugin como este: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-simple-volume

Aquí tengo una captura del componente nativo y otro del componente que quiero usar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo has instalado el plugin? ¿Lo has hecho así?: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-simple-volume@latest` ¿o de otra manera?

Comment: Si, lo he instalado así, pero ahora no se como usarlo ya que no es @ionic-native, ¿como lo importo para usarlo?

Comment: Una vez que lo instalas lo puedes importar como cualquier otra dependencia.

Comment: No puedo importarlo como cualquier otra dependencia ya que no es @ionic-native, ¿por favor me podrías indicar como lo importas tú?